# Custom CSS for Entity Print Views

Tags: views, commerce

I need to print `Cart form` view in drupal 8 site. I have installed `Entity Print` & `Entity Print Views`. I can generate pdf successfully using `tcpdf` pdf file or `debug` version does not considering css. How can I apply custom CSS to pdf file?
So far I have added below code in `mytheme.libraries.yml`

```
  print-styling:
   css:
     theme:
        css/print-style.css: {}
```

and in `entity_print.libraries.yml`

```
css:
layout:
  css/entity-print.css: {}
theme:
  css/entity-print.css: {}
```

And added custom css in `entity-print.css`, `Enable Default CSS` checkboox is not checked, added `{{ entity_print_css }}` brfore `</head>` in twig file. Still it is not working
Edited: Passing inline CSS is working for `debug` version but not in pdf

Comment: Does tcpdf even allow you to style the output? How are you testing the print css? Do you see the changes when you Print preview in your browser?

Comment: no, I can not see the css changes in browser